# How I can write same code using Delegate/Callback?

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, async-await

Here is a very simple example that is available on the internet of **Async/Await** concept, I wonder how this little logic can be implemented using **Begin/End Invoke**?
All I need to do is prepare a complicated logic using both approaches (*Async/Await and delegates*), So I want to get a start from a basic workflow.

```
int countCharacters()
    {

        int count = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader= new StreamReader("D:\\Data.txt"))
        {
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            count = content.Length;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
            return count; 
    }
    private async void btnProcessFIle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<int> task = new Task<int>(countCharacters);
        task.Start();
        int count = await task;
        lblCount.Text = "No. of characters in file=" +Environment.NewLine+ count.ToString();


    }
```

Comment: I'm curious. Why would you want to take perfectly good async/await code and convert it to using Begin/End Invoke? Begin/End invoke is the old way of doing it. Once you start using async/await there is no reason apart from submitting a homework assignment that you would need to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? What _specifically_ are you having trouble with? Taken literally, it's not possible to do what you want using _only_ `Begin/EndInvoke()`, because they don't include the feature `await` has of bringing you back to the correct thread when done. You'd need to add a call to `Control.Invoke()` to accomplish that, or use `Progress<T>`, or use `SynchronizationContext`, or...  Well, as you can see, your question is far too broad, in addition to not including a good [mcve] helping us understand what it is you actually need help with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho What I know is:
Await is a suspension point when I call any method with this KW within async method the function will run in the background. All I want to map same logic using painful structure Begin/EndInvoke. 
As Delegates are the traditional way of asynchronous programmin while Async/Await has been with us since version 4.5.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing- Sir, I agree with you this is what I need to show to others (My teammates) thus I have asked this.

Comment: @Eqra the question's code is buggy. You should't use cold tasks, just use Task.Run. Furthermore, you shouldn't use Task.Run if an asynchronous method is already available. Otherwise, you just waste a thread. Use `ReadToEndAsync` instead of `ReadToEnd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is a very simple example that is available on the internet of Async/Await concept

This is a very bad example.

It uses the task constructor and `Start`, which is a clear no-no (there are literally *no* valid use cases to do this).

It also uses the filesystem synchronously on a background thread in an "async example".

If you want an example of how to consume synchronous (e.g., CPU-bound) code asynchronously, then this is a much better example that pretty much does the same thing:

```
int countCharacters()
{
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  return 13;
}

private async void btnProcessFIle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var count = await Task.Run(() => countCharacters());
  lblCount.Text = "No. of characters in file=" + count;
}
```

Note that this is an example of *how to call CPU-bound code from the UI thread asynchronously* - it is *not* an example of the "asynchronous concept".

> I wonder how this little logic can be implemented using Begin/End Invoke?

Since your work is synchronous work on a background thread, that's actually pretty easy; [you can just use `Delegate.BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of creating your own `IAsyncResult` (which is the really hard part about APM - if you do need to implement it, see "Implementing the CLR Asynchronous Programming Model" in the [2007-03 issue of MSDN Magazine](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineMarch2007en-us.chm)).

But since you can just use `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, it's pretty straightforward:

```
private void btnProcessFIle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var ui = SynchronizationContext.Current;
  Func<int> d = countCharacters;
  d.BeginInvoke(CountCharactersCallback, ui);
}

private void CountCharactersCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
{
  var d = (Func<int>) ((AsyncResult) ar).AsyncDelegate;
  var ui = (SynchronizationContext) ar.AsyncState;
  try
  {
    var count = d.EndInvoke(ar);
    ui.Post(CountCharactersComplete, count);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    var edi = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
    ui.Post(CountCharactersError, state);
  }
}

private void CountCharactersComplete(object state)
{
  var count = (int) state;
  lblCount.Text = "No. of characters in file=" + count;
}

private void CountCharactersError(object state)
{
  var edi = (ExceptionDispatchInfo)state;
  edi.Throw();
}
```

Notes:

- `CountCharactersCallback` is a "bare callback". Any exceptions propagated from `CountCharactersCallback` indicate a catastrophic error.
- In particular, one must be careful not to allow exceptions from `EndInvoke` to propagate out of the `BeginInvoke` callback. This is a common mistake.
- I'm using `SynchronizationContext` to sync back to the UI thread. This is the same behavior as `await`.
- I'm using `ExceptionDispatchInfo` to preserve the exception stack trace across threads (without requiring a wrapper exception).
- The `CountCharactersError` just raises the exception directly on the message loop. This is the same behavior as `async void`.

Comment: Wonderful answer, I am glad you considered my question -:).
I wanna ask 2 things, the link you have provided is broken or not downloadable secondly can you please explain this.
**Note that this is an example of how to call CPU-bound code from the UI thread asynchronously - it is not an example of the "asynchronous concept".** or could you provide any link to make this statement understandable for me.

Comment: 1) You have to Unblock the file (right-click, under Properties). 2) The original example [uses `Task.Run` for the wrong thing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html).

Answer (score 0):

Feature BeginInvoke is access to the UI elements inside non-UI thread, so you need change your code like this:

```
    private async void btnProcessFIle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => {
     var count = countCharacters();
     lblCount.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
       {
         lblCount.Text = "No. of characters in file=" +Environment.NewLine+ 
            count.ToString();
       }));
    });

    await task;

}
```

Comment: Neither I want to use *Task* nor async or await. All I want to achieve using this Delegate, CallBack, BeginInvoke and EndInvoke. am I asking really much?

Comment: @Eqra - Task and async/await was created for implementing TAP - if you want just using multithreading only - no problem ( but why ? - in that case your btnProcessFIle_Click() was "frozen" while wating end of task ) - example you can find in msdn , in "Task Class" deinition https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: That's not what the OP asked. The question was *not* how to update the UI. It was how to use the APM model, ie BeginReadToEnd, etc

Answer (score -1):

Code without async / await. You don't need to use BeginInvoke because you can capture the context with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`

```
int countCharacters()
    {

        int count = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader= new StreamReader("D:\\Data.txt"))
        {
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            count = content.Length;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
            return count; 
    }


    private  void btnProcessFIle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<int> task = new Task<int>(countCharacters);
        task.Start();
        var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        task.ContinueWith(count =>{

                 lblCount.Text = "No. of characters in file=" +Environment.NewLine+ count.ToString();   
        }, uiScheduler);
    }
```

If you really want to use BeginInvoke I guess you could write

```
    private  void btnProcessFIle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<int> task = new Task<int>(countCharacters);
        task.Start();
        var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        task.ContinueWith(count =>{
                 lblCount.BeginInvoke(()=>{
                     lblCount.Text = "No. of characters in file=" +Environment.NewLine+ count.ToString();
                 });

        });
    }
```